Parametrise colors for uv-unwrapped model
I have an UV-unwrapped model that I want to color. The thing is it has very few colors, but that have smooth transitions. An example could be cartoon-ish character face with skin color, lips, possibly blush on cheeks. I want to make that colors customizable by using BW masks and mix nodes. My problem is that to do that I need a mask for each color (different mask for lips, blush etc), which is a huge waste of resources (every mask is 1K resolution raster with 80-90% just black space) and very uncomfortable to work with (need to open specific mask to edit, even though  it'd be easier to edit the in one raster).
Is there a common/accepted way to mask all 'features' on single raster map, but somehow apply different color to each feature?
Some approaches I thought of:

Baking is not an option, because the model will be exported to game engine and should still be customizable;
Unwrapping each feature area separately seems solve the resource-wasting aspect, but feels very clunky and badly scales (if I want to add scars, tatoos etc);
Maybe square-ing down those areas, but no idea how;
Maybe color each area in specific color, then mix by color but again no idea how to do it.

Here is a quick and simple example of what I mean.

the resulting model with colors:

masks for blush, lips (mouth), eyes respectivly:



simplified shader nodes for that:


That I want is to have single map for areas and somehow decide which color assign to each area.
I mentioned "resource" wasting, but my main problem is that having such a clutter of maps for each object quickly becomes an issue usability-wise.

It's a bit hard to understand your question without any image or blend file. Note that if your textures are PNG and black&white only (I mean only black and only white, not grayscale), you'll get small size png. Your 1K texture could be in the order of 100KB, so no "huge waste of ressources" as you said. I would even guess that multiple B&W textures would weight more or less the same as one single grayscale texture.

I meant grayscale. I'll try to post some sample images to clarify what I mean
